# Followed sites don't appear in "Share with" list

Tags: 2013, newsfeed, following

**SCENARIO**

I'm facing a problem about following sites: They are shown in Following section but they don't appear in "Share with" list in Newsfeed.

**DETAILS**

I follow 3 sites and on the right I see correctly 3 sites followed.

[image: I'm following area]

But in the "Share With" area I don't see following sites.

[image: share with area]

Do you know why I see this behaviour?

Comment: DO they have the Newsfeed feature enabled?

Comment: Yes they have Newsfeed enabled.

Comment: Have you been following them for a while, or can it be a job /crawl that needs to run before they are visible in that list?

Comment: Incremental Crawl runs every 15 minutes, Full crawl runs every night and I am following this sites from more than two days.

Comment: OK, are the sites publishing sites or Team sites?

Comment: They are Project Sites with Publishing features active

Comment: Thank you Robert for the point: the problem was that, in that sites, Site Feeds feature was not active.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that, in these sites, the **Site Feed** Features was not Active (because site Publishing Template, by default, don't enable Site Feed features. As soon as I enabled the feature, "share with " has work .